# @Autowiring from another service class returning null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I am trying to call a class from another class by autowiring and it is returning a null.
I have two fields autowired, one works but the other does not work.

This is the class I am trying to autowire and I am trying to get 'apppointmentAlertDays':

```
@Service
public class AlertsService {

public final Integer appointmentAlertDays;

public AlertsService(@Value("${alerts.appointment-alert-days}") Integer appointmentAlertDays){
    this.appointmentAlertDays = appointmentAlertDays;
}
```

This is the class I am trying to call "AlertsService" in, however appointmentRepository does not return a null:

```
@Service
public class AppointmentAlertProvider implements AlertProvider {
@Autowired
private AppointmentRepository appointmentRepository;

@Autowired
private AlertsService alertsService;

@Override
public List<AppointmentEntity> findLatest(String customerId) {
    Integer alertDays = alertsService.appointmentAlertDays;
}
```

This is where I am calling the "findLatest(String customerId)" method:

```
 @Test
void findLatest() {
    Appointment appointmentRequest = generateDummyAppointment();
    Vehicle vehicle = generateDummyVehicle();
    AppointmentEntity appointmentEntity = appointmentMapper.map(appointmentRequest, vehicle, null);

    when(appointmentRepository.findAllByCustomerId(anyString())).thenReturn(List.of(appointmentEntity));

    List<AppointmentEntity> appointmentEntities = appointmentAlertProvider.findLatest("customerId");

    assertThat(appointmentEntities.size()).isOne();
}
```

This is where AppointmentAlertProvider is instantiated:

```
@Component
public class AlertProviderFactory {

private AlertProviderFactory(){}

public static AlertProvider getAlertProvider(String alertType) {
    if (alertType == null || alertType.isEmpty())
            return null;
    if ("appointment-alert".equals(alertType)) {
        return new AppointmentAlertProvider();
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown alertType " + alertType);
}
```

My question is, how do I get 'appointmentAlertDays' from AlertsService? Thank you.

Comment: Where are you calling `findLatest`? I cannot reproduce this.

Comment: @Unmitigated from an interface

Comment: Can you show the code that calls it?

Comment: @Unmitigated public interface AlertProvider {
    List<AppointmentEntity> findLatest(String customerId);
}

Comment: That's the method definition, not where the method is called.

Comment: @Unmitigated sorry, my bad. it is currently being called by a test class.                  
   Test
    void findLatest() {
        List<AppointmentEntity> appointmentEntities =appointmentAlertProvider.findLatest("customerId");
        assertThat(appointmentEntities.size()).isOne();
    }

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and include the full test class where that happens? How is `AppointmentAlertProvider` instantiated?

Comment: If  Spring doesn't autowire your `AppointmentRepository` then it is because it can't find it.  I am guessing you forgot to annotate the `AppointmentRepository` or speficied the `@ComponentScan` to look in a different package

Comment: @Asgarov it does autowire the AppointmentRepository, yet does not with AlertService

Comment: See [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19896870). If you are creating your `AppointmentAlertProvider` using the constructor, it will not be a Spring Bean and `@Autowire` will therefore not do anything i that instance.